# Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error issue on android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm currently using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I've encountered this error. I've tried a lot of ways such as `uninstalling` and `reinstalling HAXM`, and even downgrading the `API` from P to 5.1. This error appears twice in my logcat, and I'm unable to solve it.

There were no issues in the building of my application, and when I run the app, I keep getting a message

> App has stopped working

What can I do to undo this problem?

Edit 1:

I had checked the logcat as directed and found that there were some attributes that were causing an issue. The attribute that was causing trouble was `<info.hoang8f.widget.FButton/>` tag, and I tried replacing it with the normal `<Button/>` tag. According to this tag, I tried to change a few things in only one XML file. It became too confusing for me that when I tried to revert back to what I had previously done, I ended up with 17 errors.

To get rid of the errors, I tried the following:

- Clean Build my Project
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Completely check my project to see if there were any other changes I had made

I've tried to find out my errors but I'm a little helpless.

I've attached the required images. I'm a newbie, really sorry if this doubt is silly.

[xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" namespace never used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RIUs.png)

[Warnings over attributes such as shadowEnabled, shadowHeight and cornerRadius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPIjS.png)

[17 errors caused after trying to revert back to old project methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g7Vj.png)

Comment: thats not logcat that's event log console!  please attach logcat as @NoumanCh said

Comment: you are always right bro it's event log.

Answer (score 0):

Steps you can perform to solve the issue

- Invalidate Android studio cache and restart it.
- Enable Haxm from bios and also from window features.
- Changing the Target from "Open Select Deployment Target Dialog" to "Emulator" in "Run/Debug Configurations".
- Try installing Geny Motion instead of using default emulator.

Comment: Where exactly can I find the Run/Debug Configurations?

Comment: from run menu options. at top of studio

Comment: I couldn't find it there in the Run menu